# Recursion with interdependency of the lower levels

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I have a program which has a number of products.
They can be either simple or composed of other products, with the ones composed having a recipe with the type and number of each component.
I need to check if I can get enough of a given product. If it is simple, I can just see if I have enough units, but if it is composed, I need to see if I can build enough copies from the rest of the products. The problem is that I can't just try to apply a Composite pattern, because the components can be composed and have products in common.
So, to illustrate, imagine that I want to see if i have enough materials to build 4 cars.
The problem would be like this:

```
Car:
   4 tires
   1 wheel
   1 chassis

Tire:
   2 rubber

Wheel:
   4 rubber

Chassis:
   10 metal

**Available**
   2 Cars
   3 Tires
   0 Wheels
   40 Metal
   12 Rubber
```

With this I can only get three cars (2+1), however, if I checked componentwise, I had enough of each material to build each one of the components for the four cars. What would be the structure of the functions that I need to implement?

Comment: Would the easiest way be to "flatten" the problem? So for each component you compute how much raw material that takes. A car is (4x2 rubber + 1x4 rubber + 1x10 metal =) 12 rubber and 10 metal. Then you also flatten your available materials by "decomposing" the composites, so you have (2x12 rubber + 2x10 metal + 3x2 rubber + 40 metal + 12 rubber =) 42 rubber and 60 metal. Now you can just per raw material compute how many cars you can make and take the minimum.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that might be a solution. I have also thought of maybe doing a copy of the database, and start removing from the copy the components while checking if i run out of something, but this solution definetly seems better

Comment: Completely flattening the problem would apparently give you more latitude than you really have, though. A car needs 12 rubbers total, but you can't take those 12 rubbers from 3 wheels, since there is at most 1 wheel per car.

Comment: Idea of algorithm: Maintain a count of all the materials that you have. Attempt to make a car by taking the required amount of tires, wheels and chassis in the materials counts. If it is possible, then increase the number of cars by 1 and decrease all the appropriate materials. If a tire is missing, then attempt to make a tire by taking the required amount of materials; same for wheel and chassis. Keep going until you have successfully make a car, or you failed to make a car. If you succeeded, loop to make a second car.